# Android dynamic check box not getting values

Tags: android

I have created a layout dynamically and added check boxes. code as follows,

```
//Load dynamic view          

List<Integer> checkBoxIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int id = 0;

ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("CatchInfo");
tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
ll.addView(tv); 
for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
{           
    ck = new CheckBox(this);
    ck.setId(id);
    checkBoxIdList.add(id);
    ck.setText(list2.get(i));
    ll.addView(ck);         
}
Button btnHome = new Button(this);
btnHome.setText("Home");
ll.addView(btnHome);
Button btnSubmit = new Button(this);
btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
ll.addView(btnSubmit);
this.setContentView(sv);
```

I am trying get value value of check box using click listner as follows:

```
ck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

        if(!isChecked){                           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {   
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
   }
});
```

But the click action is only taken place in last check box and in others it is not responding. How can solve this and how will I get values?

Comment: Are you adding the listener inside the for loop, or outside of the for loop?

Comment: It is outside the loop, that is why I added ids. May be with Ids it can be figure out outside the loop

Comment: How will I get values on click of check box dude??

Comment: @androidsuckzzz check my answer below. Hopefully it helps you. I didn't get to know what is `list2`, so I created `String[] list2`. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your function to handle the onCheckedChangeListener.. See the below code.

```
List<Integer> checkBoxIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int id = 0;
String[] list2 = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("CatchInfo");
tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
ll.addView(tv); 
for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
{           
    ck = new CheckBox(this);
    ck.setId(id);
    checkBoxIdList.add(id);
    ck.setTag(list2[i]); // set the tag values so that you can refer to them later.
    ll.addView(ck);         
    ck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(handleCheck(ck));  //Calling the function, add this line in your code
}
Button btnHome = new Button(this);
btnHome.setText("Home");
ll.addView(btnHome);
Button btnSubmit = new Button(this);
btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
ll.addView(btnSubmit);
this.setContentView(sv);
```

**Here is the function which handles the check events**

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener handleCheck (final CheckBox chk)
    {
        return new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!isChecked){                           
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You unchecked " + chk.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You checked " + chk.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this.

```
     for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
 {           
   CheckBox ck = new CheckBox(this);
   ck.setId(id);
   checkBoxIdList.add(id);
   ck.setText(list2.get(i));
   ck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

    if(!isChecked){                           
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {   
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
   }
   }); 
    ll.addView(ck);         
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to increment in id variable.
thats y all checkboxes you are adding will get same id.

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxesList2 = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

    for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
    {           
        ck = new CheckBox(this);
        ck.setId(id);
        checkBoxIdList.add(id);
        checkBoxesList2.add(ck);
        id++;
        ck.setText(list2.get(i));
        ll.addView(ck);         
    }

    for(int i=0;i<checkBoxesList2.size();i++){
    ck =(CheckBox) checkBoxesList2.get(i);
    ck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

            if(!isChecked){                           
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
       }
    }); 
    }
```

Comment: yah, but how can I get values of this check box?? I tried but not working for me.

Comment: shujatAli Not working. How I need to get values of check boxes on click of that particular box?